# How to convert date to GMT format using oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to convert my user selected date into GMT format and store in DB.

Query:

```
select cast('7/1/2015 12:00:00 AM' as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' from dual
```

The following error is thrown:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

The query works fine when month is mentioned as Jan. But I dont find any GMT conversion in it.Similarly how to change the month to MMM without changing the hh:mm:ss. Kindly help

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? And is there any reason you need to send the value to Oracle as *text* instead of as a timestamp value? Also note that GMT isn't a "format" - it's a time zone. (Well, sort of. I'd use UTC myself, which is also not strictly speaking a time zone, but a time zone-like frame of reference.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Mentioned C# as I found java providing few methods to convert to timestamp

Comment: Um, I don't understand what you mean. If you mean "I'm sending this string from C# code" then the best solution would be to perform the conversion *in* C# (to DateTimeOffset or DateTime) and then send that value in the query, using parameterized SQL. You haven't given us enough context for what you're doing though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
select cast(to_date('7/1/2015 12:00:00 AM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' from dual
```